# Elegant way to replace switch structure

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have simple random number generated and I want to perform different actions according to the generated value. I have 9 different actions. I can't use `switch` structure on `double` values and I can't cast from `double` to `int` to use `switch` so am I doomed to use `if` structure ?

```
if((rand > 0.0) && (rand < 1.0))
   // case 1
else if...
   // case 2
else if
   // case 9
```

**EDIT :** note that my actions aren't equiprobable

Comment: What's so ugly about `if/else` that's not about `switch`?

Comment: why can't you cast to int?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show other conditions.

Comment: multiply your rand with 10, then cast to an int.

Comment: @Alexis : I prefer switch for multiple choices, it's more readable I think.

Comment: @jtahlborn : we can't cast from double to int because they extend both java.lang.Number or I don't know the way to do this

Comment: so you are talking about `Integer` and `Double`, not `int` and `double`...

Comment: @Frank : nice it's work but why casting from double to int works and casting from double to Integer fails ? Thank you

Comment: @Alexis : yes sorry it was the case. I don't really understand difference between int and Integer it seems...

Comment: @OlivierJ. the cast works like a round down, so you always get 0..

Comment: You can compose Strategy objects into a Factory and Mediate between your options but it wont't be better than this just fancier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to your answers and @dasblinkenlight, I found custom solution to my problem :

```
static final Map<Integer, Double> cases = new HashMap<Integer, Double>(9);

static{             
    cases.put(1, 30.0);
    cases.put(2, 55.0);     
    cases.put(3, 70.0);     
    cases.put(4, 80.0);     
    cases.put(5, 84.0);     
    cases.put(6, 88.0);     
    cases.put(7, 92.0);     
    cases.put(8, 96.0);     
    cases.put(9, 100.0);
}

switch (getIntFromDouble(Math.random()*100)) {
    case 0 : ...
        break;

    case 1 : ...
        break;

    ...     

    case 9 : ...
        break;

}

private int getIntFromDouble(double rand){

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : cases.entrySet()){
        if(rand <= entry.getValue())
            return entry.getKey();
    }

    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of inverting the solution like that? You are using the map as a list of pairs because of that loop. In addition, it's not guaranteed to do the right thing, because you are using a hash map in place of a tree map. My solution, on the other hand, would give the right result: just plug in your numbers in reverse, and try it out.

Comment: yes you're right, I have to use tree map. Thank you to notice me

Answer (score 2):

Create a `static TreeMap<Double,Integer>` with interval limits mapping to an integer "case label". Use the [`higerEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#higherEntry%28K%29) method to obtain the entry for the value nearest to your randomly generated `double`, and use the resultant value in your `switch` statement.

```
static final TreeMap<Double,Integer> limits = new TreeMap<Double,Integer>();
static {
    limits.put(1.0, 0);
    limits.put(3.5, 1);
    limits.put(8.0, 2);
    limits.put(10.3, 3);
}
```

This map sets up fiveintervals:

- -inf..1.0
- 1.0..3.5
- 3.5..8.0
- 8.0..10.3
- 10.3..+inf

Now in your code you can do this:

```
double someNumber = ... // Obtain a random double
Map<Double,Integer> entry = higerEntry(someNumber);
switch (entry.getValue()) {
    case 0: ... break;
    case 1: ... break;
    case 2: ... break;
    case 3: ... break;
    default: ... break;
}
```

Comment: very nice way but why using `static` Map and not Map linked to my object instance ?

Comment: @OlivierJ. I am assuming that the distributions of probabilities are not dependent on your object instance. In this case, you do not need a separate copy of the same map in each instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, Some code:

```
    switch ((int) (rand * 10)) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Between 0 and 3");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("4");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("5");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("6");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("More then 6");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: can we use somthing like "between" with switch ? case between 0 and 3 for example ?

Comment: I can't use this because I will have 100 case...I think I will use if structure

Answer (score 0):

Provided the actions are equiprobable, you could just use `Random.nextInt()` with an upper bound, and a `switch`:

```
      Random rand = new Random();
      ...
      switch (rand.nextInt(10)) {
      case 0: ...; break;
      case 1: ...; break;
      case 9: ...; break;
      }
```

You can use the same technique with a `[0, 1)` floating-point random number. Just multiply it by `10` and cast to `int`.

Comment: My actions aren't equiprobable ;)

Comment: @OlivierJ.: Then please clearly state your requirements in your questions. Otherwise we're left guessing at what it is that you need.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use the rounding?

```
int value=Math.round(yourDouble)
```

Comment: The problem with round is that it adjusts the probabilities in an unexpected way. In order for `Math.round(yourDouble)` to result in 0, yourDouble must be less than 0.5. But for the result to be one, we can have a range of 0.5 <= yourDouble < 1.5. This makes 1 twice as likely as 0.